# Find it hard to do

Tags: grammaticality

> You can make the things easy which you find it hard to do.

Should I use **it** in sentence above? What I want to say is that There are things and I found doing things hard  and ı want to make things easier. I though “it” modifies “ to do” .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pronoun `it` is not necessary here, it makes the sentence non-grammatical.  If it did occur in that position, it would not modify `to do`, but would be an object of the clause which references `the things`.

Also, the word order is incorrect.  Instead, say:

> You can make the things which you find hard to do easier.

Comment: "Did he find it easy to write?"  is fine and correct grammar.  The difference is that `it` is the object of `find` there, in a primary SVO clause.  On the other hand, `which you find hard to do` is an adjective clause, it does not take a separate subject but refers to `the things` by its place in the sentence.   (edit:  it looks like you deleted your comment asking about "did he find it easy to write?", but I will leave my reply here anyway!)

Comment: `You can make the things which you find to hard to do easy.` is correct grammar.  A speaker would place a little pause in between `do` and `easy` if saying that, so that `hard` and `easy` don't "crash".  It sounds as if there is a comma, but do not write a comma.

Comment: I understood my problem in this sentenrence thanks for your help.